# SSH Can't authenticate 18.04

Tags: ssh

I had my SSH desktop configured this morning and could SSH to my machine remotely. I decided to re-install SSH onto the Desktop and now I'm not able to ssh in. Does anyone know why?

```
$ ssh -vvv -p 22 apples@applesauce.ddns.net
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "applesauce.ddns.net" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to applesauce.ddns.net [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_2015.67
debug1: no match: dropbear_2015.67
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to applesauce.ddns.net:22 as 'apples'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/apples/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from applesauce.ddns.net
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug2: bits set: 1015/2048
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:rdRZ6flnFe84+P6tURzH9I8JgO5BQf9h75wtZaAflAY
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/apples/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from applesauce.ddns.net
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/apples/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/apples/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 
debug1: Host 'applesauce.ddns.net' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/apples/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug2: bits set: 1027/2048
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:bWkJ9jZHO1vvmcm7mn9xL/W6HoRLoMjV0j277G3OBiw
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:bWkJ9jZHO1vvmcm7mn9xL/W6HoRLoMjV0j277G3OBiw
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/apples/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password

apples@applesauce.ddns.net's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: Are you expecting to use key based auth or password auth?

Comment: Key based @Seth

Comment: Is this machine running through the Windows Subsystem for Linux? These paths (`/c/Users/apples/.ssh/known_hosts`) look like Windows paths. Can you provide more details about how you reinstalled ssh on your desktop?

Comment: Have you tried using `ssh -i` and manually specifying which key you want to use? Right now it looks like the ssh client can't find your private key locally.

Comment: @Seth, I uninstall using sudo apt-get purge openssh-client, then re-installed client/server. I'm trying to connect from my laptop, but on my desktop I'm running ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @Seth, Do I need the public key of ~/.ssh/id_dsa,
             ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/id_rsa to auth?

Answer (score 1):

I had a router/modem combo and after calling my ISP and successfully being emailed a guide on how to bridge the network, I was able to SSH and work remotely from now on.